# How to remove leading "f" when parsing Long using toHexString

Tags: java, java-8, bit-manipulation

I am writing unit tests for my project trying to check the value of a `long` in hex string format using the method `Long.toHexString(l)`.

When I test using `long` equals `111` I get the value `6f` which is correct and as I  expected.

But when long is `-64` I expect `c0` but instead, I get `ffffffffffffffc0`.

From reading the Java Doc I can see that the method is expecting an unsigned long and if it's passed a negative value then returns the 2s complement. But how to correct this?

I have written a small unit test program to demonstrate,

```
@Test
public void long_to_hex() {
   Long l = new Long(-64);
   //Long l = new Long(111);
   System.out.println(l.toHexString(l));
}
```

Comment: "But how to correct this?" Why do you think this is wrong? As you have already read the documentation, you should understand why it returns what it returns, and that the behaviour _you_ want is non-standard. Can you explain what's your logic behind expecting `c0`? Isn't `c0` the hex of 192?

Comment: @Sweeper I think he means withdrawal of the leading `f`s

Comment: @snr Yes, but why? The leading `f`s are correct.

Comment: @DavidConrad without any hesitation.

Comment: `Long l = new Long(-64);` -> `long l = -64;`. `l.toHexString(l)` -> `Long.toHexString(l)`.

Comment: ok - thank you for your comments - its my bad I was getting myself confused. I understand that the value is correctly returning now. Please see my updated comments to Holger's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement “if it’s passed a negative value then returns the 2s complement” does not match [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toHexString-long-):

> The unsigned long value is the argument plus 2⁶⁴ if the argument is negative; otherwise, it is equal to the argument.

So it’s actually the opposite, the value you pass in is already using the 2s complement, but the returned value is a string capable of reproducing the right `long` bits even when not being interpreted as 2s complement. In other words, in your `long` value, all upper bits are set, hence, the hexadecimal representation has the corresponding number of leading `f` characters.

The alternative is to keep the representation signed:

```
long l = -64;
System.out.println(Long.toHexString(l));
System.out.println(Long.toString(l, 16));
```

```
ffffffffffffffc0
-40
```

Comment: thank you for your post. I was getting myself confused. My use case is as follows. I have an array of bytes [] that I need to check the values of for my test. One value is 192 (which is part of an IP-address). The byte value is -64 but the hex value that it should be represented by is c0. The reason I have the leading f's is because I am storing the value as a signed value and it should be an unsigned value. byte -64 as an unsigned value (using int) is 192 and 192 as hex is c0. Maybe I should update the question to make this clear?

Comment: When your data is actually a `byte`, using `Long` is a strange choice. When you use `byte b1 = -64; String str = Integer.toHexString(b1 & 0xff); byte b2 = (byte)Integer.parseInt(str, 16);`, then, the string will be `"c0"` and `b1 == b2`.

Comment: Alternatively, `Integer.toHexString(Byte.toUnsignedInt(b1))` does the same.

Comment: thank you Holger, thats excellent - you've really understood my issue. I can use your suggested technique, Byte.toUnsignedInt(b1) - which does the trick for me.